# CosmosDB SQL query on child item in array with a given conditiion

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am working with CosmosDB and I have to do with a collection which looks like the following

```
[
  {
    "detected": [
      {
        "class": "person",
        "probability": 94.24896240234375,
        "centroid": {
          "x": 242,
          "y": 151
        },
        "is_tracked": false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "detected": [
      {
        "class": "person",
        "probability": 64.25231099128723,
        "centroid": {
          "x": 355,
          "y": 259
        },
        "is_tracked": true
      },
      {
        "class": "person",
        "probability": 50.44138431549072,
        "centroid": {
          "x": 185,
          "y": 183
        },
        "is_tracked": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to write a SQL query that allows me to select all the `x`, `y` values within the `centroid` object only where `is_tracked` is set to `true`.
In principle, the query that I'm looking for would return something like the following:

```
[
  {
    "x": 355,
    "y": 259
  },
  {
    "x": 185,
    "y": 183
  }
]
```

I've already tried

`SELECT c.detected FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.detected, {'is_tracked': true}, true)`

and I get what I posted above. However, I don't know how to further filter.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: It did indeed! Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below sql:

```
SELECT detect.centroid.x as x,detect.centroid.y as y FROM c
join detect in c.detected
where detect.is_tracked = true
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @FabrizioMiano You're welcome. If you don't mind,you could accept it as an answer  to end this case(the hook beside my answer)!